# How to verify that AD Groups synched using User Profile Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, groups

Our AD administrator has just set up about 10 AD groups that I want to synch with the User Profile Service for SP 2010. Seems like the synch runs fine without error but now I am having trouble verifying that these groups have synched properly. Another words, I want to proof that the groups synched by confirming through navigating the site. Should I be able to see the group as an audience?  For instance when I go to set up an audience I want to map an audience to the AD group that I synched(eg. Development Group)  When I search on the group no results come back.  I am new to synchronizing groups so its matter of understanding what I should be able to do once the synch completes.  My hunch is that they haven't synched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have windows security groups and membership synchronized properly, I am able to resolve group names while adding a new Audience and add a rule (operand = user, operator= member of, value = name of windows security group).

Comment: This did it.  Not sure why the initial synchronization didn't result in the groups appearing when I set up audiences like your answer. However, after trying to establish audiences a second time they were there and all is well.